# How to add label to an issue on GitHub

Tags: git, github, github-issues

I have recently created a new issue on my repository on GitHub, now I want to add a label to it, the issue is actually a bug. I don't know how to do it. I am the owner of that repository.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I find out how to label an issue, it actually simple

1. Create a issue from issue tab
2. Click on labels, a popup will open

[image]
[image]

3. Enter the label name & click create new label & then save

[image]
[image]

Label will be added, as simple as that.

Comment: i dont understand 2 point how i check this and further detail kindly show details with picture how to do these steps thanks

Answer (score 6):

Actually useful answer:

The UI does not make this readily apparent, but as a regular user you ***cannot*** add labels to an issue, you need triage access to that repository, even if you're the author.

The documentation for creating and applying labels can be found [here](https://docs.github.com/en/issues/using-labels-and-milestones-to-track-work/managing-labels#applying-a-label).